# Categories list pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I used the following code in admin_index() method that is in CategoriesController

```
$this->set('title_for_layout', __('Categories', true));
$treelist = $this->Category->generateTreeList(null, null, null, '_');
$categories = $this->Category->children();
$i = 0;

foreach ($treelist as $value) {
    $categories[$i]['Category']['path'] = $value;
    $i++;
}

$this->set(compact('categories'));
```

How can I paginate categories list?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've followed any of the pagination documentation.  You need to use the pagination helper and component for standard pagination to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call paginate.

```
$this->set('categories', $this->paginate());
```

You will need to make sure you have the pagination controls in the view.